# How do I rename a sharePoint file to include a date using Nintex

Tags: sharepoint-2013, inline-functions, nintex-workflow

I'm trying to use a 2 workflows to archive any files when created or updated. The first simply moves a copy to a separate doc library. no issues
The second should rename the file once it arrives to append a date (and possible timestamp) to the end of the file so that it is a unique record.

I am trying to set a variable called Archive_Name and then setting the field value to the Archive_Name before commiting the change.

I am using this fomula to set the variable

Name-fn-FormatDate(Current Date,yyyy-MM-dd)

Both Name and Current Date are recognised variable.

When I run this the Name stays the same and does not append a date. If I run it as

fn-FormatDate(Current Date,yyyy-MM-dd)

the Name changes to my desired date proving that the formula is working, the text is being assigned to the Archive_Date variable and the variable is being applied to the field value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to concatenate the two variables. The **&** operator can be used in place of the CONCATENATE function. Thus; **Name&fn-FormatDate(Current Date,yyyy-MM-dd)**

Hope this helps